# cursor count is 1 whereas the table has 3 rows

Tags: android-sqlite

I m trying to populate sql table and then retrieve data from it. Following is my code.

```
public void addQuestion(Question quest)
{
    int id = 1;
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_QUEST1);
    onCreate(db);
    values.put(KEY_QUES, quest.getQuestion());
    values.put(KEY_ANSWER, quest.getAnswer());
    values.put(KEY_OPTA, quest.getOptA());
    values.put(KEY_OPTB, quest.getOptB());
    values.put(KEY_OPTC, quest.getOptC());
    db.insert(TABLE_QUEST1, null, values);
    System.out.println("Added in database: " + quest.getQuestion());
}

public ArrayList<Question> getAllQuestions() {
    System.out.println("getting rows 1");
    ArrayList<Question> quesList = new ArrayList<Question>();
    System.out.println("getting rows 2");
    Cursor cursor = null;
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    System.out.println("getting rows ");
    cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_QUEST1, null);
    if (!cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        System.out.println("No data in the database ");
    } else {
        System.out.println("theres data in the database ");
        quesList = new ArrayList<Question>();
        do {
            System.out.print("total rows " + cursor.getCount());
            Question quest = new Question();
            quest.setID(cursor.getInt(0));
            quest.setQuestion(cursor.getString(1));
            quest.setAnswer(cursor.getString(2));
            quest.setOptA(cursor.getString(3));
            quest.setOptB(cursor.getString(4));
            quest.setOptC(cursor.getString(5));
            quesList.add(quest);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        cursor.close();
    }
}
```

I have 4 rows of data in my table and I can see that with the print statement "added in database"

but when i actually read it the cursor just reads row 1 and moves out of the while loop. what could potentially be wrong.

tia

Comment: You're dropping and recreating the table each time you add to it. Don't do that.

Comment: DROP TABLE on each insert ? Why ? In this way there will be only one row entire time.

Comment: You are dropping table db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_QUEST1); and recreating table. Thats why only one record exists in table.

Comment: reformatted code to be indented.

Comment: Changed tag to android-sqllite

Comment: it works..thanku..

Comment: @JyotiGulati If an answer resolves your problem then please mark it as answered, if you find answers or comments helpful you could also consider up-voting them.

Comment: Sure Mike ..thx..I tried upvoting but I am a new user and looks like I need to be around for some more time to upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code was absolutely fine except placing drop command in the loop. As mentioned in the earlier comments, please make sure to avoid calling drop query each time and you'll find the result.

Comment: thanku...but if i just do oncreate, I get an error saying table already created

Comment: Or else you try to drop table only if the table exists AND is empty.

Comment: thx it worked...I am loading this data from JSON file. Now when I change the JSON file, I want the older data in the table to be  flushed out so that I can insert new one. Where shuld the delete /drop tale be placed to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

As Santosh has pointed out DROPPING the table (as per `db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_QUEST1);`) and then re-creating it (as per `onCreate(db);`) will delete the table and then re-create the table removing any rows/data that had previously been added to the table.

As such it's simply a matter of removing those two lines of code, Also there appears to be no need for the line `int id = 1;`, so perhaps remove this,  as per :-

```
public void addQuestion(Question quest)
{
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    values.put(KEY_QUES, quest.getQuestion());
    values.put(KEY_ANSWER, quest.getAnswer());
    values.put(KEY_OPTA, quest.getOptA());
    values.put(KEY_OPTB, quest.getOptB());
    values.put(KEY_OPTC, quest.getOptC());
    db.insert(TABLE_QUEST1, null, values);
    System.out.println("Added in database: " + quest.getQuestion());
}
```

P.S. you may consider not using hard coded column offsets but instead obtain offsets according to column names by utilising the `getColumnIndex(column_name)` Cursor method. e.g. :-

```
        Question quest = new Question();
        quest.setID(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("name_of_your_id_columm")));
        quest.setQuestion(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_QUES)));
        quest.setAnswer(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ANSWER)));
        quest.setOptA(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_OPTA)));
        quest.setOptB(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_OPTB)));
        quest.setOptC(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_OPTC)));
        quesList.add(quest);
```

Noting that instead of `"name_of_your_id_columm"`, you may have something like `KEY_ID` defined, if so use that, thus you have a single definition so it reduces the chance of inadvertently mispelling column names or miscalculating the offsets.